# how to call methods of defined classes from within template class methods

Tags: c++, templates

How should I call a method within a defined class from a template class method?
Below is my scenario -

1. Template Class

   ```
   template <class T>
   class TC {
       void myTemplateMethod() {
           T.myMethod();  //can I call like this ?
       }
   };
   ```
2. Defined Class

   ```
   class tdef {
       void myMethod() { 
           //does something
       }
   };
   ```
3. Main

   ```
   int main()  {
       TC<tdef> tobj;
       tobj.myTemplateMethod(); //can I call tdef.myMethod() like this?
   }
   ```

Just to note, that I have debugged a code like this and have found that tdef.myMethod() does not work when called like this. Also are there any chances that some exceptions are not handled while calling tdef.myMethod() from within Template class method?

-Somnath

Comment: There's no such thing as `tdef.myMethod()`.  `tdef` is a class name, not an object, and the `.` member-access operator requires an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a non-static member function, so it can only be called on an instance.  Templates don't change that fact.

```
T t;
t.myMethod();
```

or if the function were static:

```
T::myMethod();
```

Comment: But I am creating an instance of the template class and so the compiler should understand that myMethod() is called through an instance. Isn't it like that?

Comment: @somnath: `myMethod` is part of the `tdef` class, so it needs an instance of `tdef` (`T` is `tdef`, inside `TC<tdef>::myTemplateMethod()`).  What you have is an instance of `TC<tdef>`, you need an instance of `tdef`.

Comment: Well, it works with static functions only. Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: yeah this means that any static class method can only be called from template class

Comment: @somnath: If you had an instance of `T` (not `TC<T>`), you could use its non-static members.